# In $\mathbb{C^2}$, show that $\langle x,y \rangle$ = $xAy^*$ is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{C^2}$, show that $\langle x,y \rangle$ = $xAy^*$ is an inner product, where

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & i \\
-i & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Property (c) of an inner product on V states that ${\langle \bar{x},\bar{y} \rangle}$ = $\langle y,x \rangle$

For part (c), I found the following answer online

> Property (c) requires a little more work: First note that since $xAy^*$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, it is equal to its transpose.  So $xAy^* = (xAy^*)^t = \bar y A^t x^t$.  Now we have
>   $$
> \overline{\langle x,y \rangle} = 
> \overline{xAy^*} = 
> \overline{\bar y A^t x^t} = 
> yA^*x^* = yAx^* = \langle y,x \rangle
> $$
>   since $A$ is self-adjoint.

[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpfqb.jpg)

For the equality, $(xAy*)^t = \bar{y}A^tx^t$, why are we able to switch $\bar{y}$ and $x^t$? Is it simply because we're dealing with a $1$x$1$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, I know what * means. I still don't see why that allows me to switch.

Comment: Honestly, if you don't understand how transpose and conjugate work, you should definitely not be looking up questions like this online. You are only hurting yourself in the long run. read your notes and textbook.

Comment: I recommend looking at the references you are using for your class and reading about those two topics.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something elementary, but going through an entire book to look for one fact would take up too much time.

Comment: I`m not sure if I understood the question right, but using $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$, we get : $(xAy^*)^t=\bar y^{t^t}A^tx^t=\bar yA^tx^t $

Comment: I completely forgot about that, thanks!

Comment: If u just needed the proof that transpose of multiplication of two of matrix is equal to the product the transpose of individual matrices in opposite order... just generalise the inner product and due to exchange in indexes in transpose LHS can be reconstituted as product of individual transpose in opposite order...the smarter thing would be to forego this and satisfy yourself with an example of your own.